# MYSQL Unique from two columns (Cross Unique)

Tags: mysql, unique

I have a table with 2 columns **'NAME'** and **'ALIAS'**.
I want the contents of both columns to be unique.
So I can't create a **'NAME'** that is already in an **'ALIAS'** and vice versa.

[image]

> 'NAME' B is not allowed because B has been previously used in column
> 'ALIAS';
>
> 'ALIAS' A is not allowed because A was previously used in column
> 'NAME';
>
> 'NAME' C is allowed because it has never been used before, both in the
> 'NAME' column and the 'ALIAS' column and 'ALIAS' D is allowed because
> it has never been used before, both in the 'NAME' column and the
> 'ALIAS' column;
>
> ...
>
> I want the Data in Column 'NAME' and Column 'ALIAS' Unique as in one
> Column

I've tried this way,

```
CREATE TABLE `Group` (
  Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  Alias VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Name)
)
ENGINE = MYISAM,
CHECKSUM = 0;

ALTER TABLE `Group` ADD CONSTRAINT Constraint_Group UNIQUE KEY(`Name`, `Alias`);
```

but Unique only applies to the respective column.

Is there a way to get it?

Thanks.

Comment: you have to handle in code using transactions

Comment: @aRvi Yes, it can be Done in my Front App too. Check row by row and add row to table. i just think how to handle this when we will use Bulk Insert/load data from file to table.

Answer (score 1):

Got Answer from [@Michael - sqlbot](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/11651/michael-sqlbot) in [this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29336/mysql-unique-constraint-across-two-columns)

Using Triger to get my Need.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Groups;

CREATE TABLE groups (
  Name varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  Alias varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Name)
)
ENGINE = MYISAM,
CHARACTER SET utf8,
CHECKSUM = 0,
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE groups
ADD UNIQUE INDEX Alias (Alias);


CREATE TRIGGER trg_Ins BEFORE INSERT ON groups FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
      DECLARE err_msg VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL; 
      
      IF EXISTS(SELECT x.alias FROM groups x WHERE x.alias = NEW.name) OR (NEW.Name=New.Alias) THEN
          SET err_msg = CONCAT_WS('','cannot insert Name value ',NEW.Name,'; already exists as a Alias');
          SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = err_msg;
      END IF;

      IF EXISTS(SELECT x.Name FROM groups x WHERE x.Name = NEW.Alias) OR (NEW.Alias=NEW.Name)  THEN
          SET err_msg = CONCAT_WS('','cannot insert Alias value ',NEW.Alias,'; already exists as a Name');
          SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = err_msg;
      END IF;
  END;

CREATE TRIGGER trg_Upd BEFORE UPDATE ON groups FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
      DECLARE err_msg VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL; 
      
      IF EXISTS(SELECT x.alias FROM groups x WHERE x.alias = NEW.name) OR (NEW.Name=New.Alias) THEN
          SET err_msg = CONCAT_WS('','cannot Update Name value ',NEW.Name,'; already exists as a Alias');
          SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = err_msg;
      END IF;

      IF EXISTS(SELECT x.Name FROM groups x WHERE x.Name = NEW.Alias) OR (NEW.Alias=NEW.Name)  THEN
          SET err_msg = CONCAT_WS('','cannot Update Alias value ',NEW.Alias,'; already exists as a Name');
          SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = err_msg;
      END IF;
  END;

-- TEST INSERT

Insert INTO Groups VALUES ('A','B');  -- OK

Insert INTO Groups VALUES ('B',NULL); -- cannot insert Name value B; already exists as a Alias 

Insert INTO Groups VALUES ('C','A'); --  cannot insert Alias value A; already exists as a Name

Insert INTO Groups VALUES ('C','D'); -- OK

Insert INTO Groups VALUES ('E','Z'); -- OK

Insert INTO Groups VALUES ('K','K'); -- cannot insert Name value K; already exists as a Alias

-- TEST UPDATE
UPDATE groups SET `Name`='A' WHERE `Name`='C'; -- Duplicate entry 'A' for key

UPDATE groups set `Name` ='X' WHERE `Name`='E'; -- OK

UPDATE groups set `Alias` ='A' WHERE `Name`='X'; -- cannot Update Name value B; already exists as a Alias
```

-- Will Try More Test

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the possible names from one table, which has a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `name` column. That way you cannot use the name for more than one purpose. To make this actual work you will need another column specifying the type of the name, if it is for the group name or for an alias. You use this column as part for the foreign key.

***Note**: For this to work you will need (and should always?) to use the [InnoDB storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-introduction.html) so you have working foreign keys.*

First you create a table for "all" the possible names.

```
CREATE TABLE names (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    kind VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT UQ_name UNIQUE(name), 
    CONSTRAINT CH_names_kind CHECK (kind IN ('name', 'alias')),
    KEY IX_names_nameAndKind (name, kind)
);
```

*(You need MySQL 8 for `CHECK` statements to work)*

As you see the `name` column has a `UNIQUE` constraint, so you can't have duplicate entries. Also every entry must be a kind of either `'name'` or `'alias'` with the `CHECK` entry and since you can't have duplicate names, you have to choose. You could fill the entries as follow:

```
INSERT INTO names (name, kind) VALUES ('A', 'name');
INSERT INTO names (name, kind) VALUES ('B', 'alias');
INSERT INTO names (name, kind) VALUES ('C', 'name');
```

Now the tricky part is the group table. You have to not just reference the column `name` but also the `kind` in combination. That is also the reason why there is a key `IX_names_nameAndKind` in the `names` table. So instead of referencing the id value of the auto increment column from the other table you reference the multi column index `name` and `kind`. You do this for the name of a group as well as for the optional alias for a group. The `CREATE TABLE` statement might look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE grps (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    nameKind VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    alias VARCHAR(300) NULL,
    aliasKind VARCHAR(15) NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY FK_grps_nameAndNameKind (name, nameKind) REFERENCES names (name, kind),
    CONSTRAINT CH_grps_nameKind CHECK (nameKind IN ('name')),
    FOREIGN KEY FK_grps_aliasAndAliasKind (alias, aliasKind) REFERENCES names (name, kind),
    CONSTRAINT CH_grps_aliasKind CHECK (aliasKind IN ('alias'))
);
```

The foreign key `FK_grps_nameAndNameKind` states, that the columns `name` and `nameKind` must be from the `names` table (with the columns `name` and `kind`). The same goes with the foreign key `FK_grps_aliasAndAliasKind` for the columns `alias` and `aliasKind`. But the trick here is to limit the `nameKind` column to allow only the value `'name'` and the `aliasKind` column to allow only the value `'alias'` (see the `CHECK` statements). So when the group name is referenced, it must be with the kind `'name'` and when the alias name is referenced, it must be with the kind `'alias'`. You can fill the table as follow:

```
INSERT INTO grps (name, nameKind, alias, aliasKind) VALUES ('A', 'name', NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO grps (name, nameKind, alias, aliasKind) VALUES ('C', 'name', 'B', 'alias');
```

When you try to break the checks and foreign keys you get error messages as expected:

```
INSERT INTO grps (name, nameKind, alias, aliasKind) VALUES ('B', 'name', NULL, NULL);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
    (`test`.`grps`, CONSTRAINT `grps_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
    (`name`, `nameKind`) REFERENCES `names` (`name`, `kind`))
```

```sql
INSERT INTO grps (name, nameKind, alias, aliasKind) VALUES ('B', 'alias', NULL, NULL);
ERROR 3819 (HY000): Check constraint 'CH_grps_nameKind' is violated.
```

Comment: Thank's for the aswer. Its Very Complex for me... Have tried Script on MYISAM, and Not Work....

Comment: @Mabaega You have to use InnoDB because this solution uses foreign keys.